# iphone to mysql blob not inserting no error

Tags: php, mysql, ios, xcode, mysqli

i'm trying to insert a blob into a mysql database along with other values, the other values go in fine and there isn't any error. the max allowed packet size is set to 10mb and the photo data is .5mb.

here is the code to convert the photo to binary:

```
- (NSData *)dataFromImage:(UIImage *)image{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    return imageData;
}
```

it is then posted to the php script:

```
$db = new mysqli(localhost, $database, $pass, $table);

if ($query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO JobData (someotherdata, photo) values (? ,?)")) {

    $query->bind_param("sb", 
            $_POST["someotherdata"],
            $_POST["photo"]);

    $query->execute();
```

The otherdata shows up in the database, but 0 bytes show up in the photo field.
mysqli_error doesn't produce any errors.

the NSData logs:

```
4f1eba47 4f37e5f1 d3475bf6 d9fef291 7b1cc893 af9e38c9 d3674fdd 13e4e9b3...etc
```

Maybe i'm not correctly turning the data into binary? i'm not able to find much about this on the web, most of what i find has to do with sqlite so any help is much appreciated.

I also check to see if all of the data is set prior to the bind_param call

Comment: Is it safe to assume that $_POST["photo"] does contain content prior to the bind_param() call?

Comment: it is only posted to once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been doing a similar project recently where I needed to upload a bunch of information (name, id, age etc) to a sql database that was accompanied by an image. Unfortunately its not as easy as just converting the data into binary and sending it, but there is an awsome piece of code that will do that for you..

```
//this is where you put in the data e.g...
 NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[_params setObject:userName forKey:@"sendername"];
//[_params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", userId] forKey:[NSString stringWithString:@"userId"]];
//[_params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_title] forKey:@"title"];

// the boundary string : a random string, that will not repeat in post data, to separate post data fields.
NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";

// string constant for the post parameter 'file'. My server uses this name: `file`. Your's may differ
NSString* FileParamConstant = @"picture";

// the server url to which the image (or the media) is uploaded. Use your server url here
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url name here"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add image data
UIImage *imageToPost = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image is here"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];

NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];



[connection start];
```

Give that a try and let me know how you get on... It might not be exactly what your looking for but hopefully it will guide you in the right direction. T

Comment: i'm using afnetworking, the data posts correctly, the photos get lost somewhere between the php script and the db, yet the other data goes through. looks like you are doing the same thing as me, just without the library, although i'm not sure because i've never used NSURLConnection.

Comment: Sweet as man, Well I will get our php man to have a look for you because I know he was just having an issue getting the image to save in the DB. I think the solution he came up with was to save the image into a tmp folder and then transfer it to a subfolder of the domain. The slqDB then simply holds the reference url to the image that can be accessed in app.. Ill get him to add some info.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to do originally, but the company wants the actual photo in the db. I'll probably end up doing it your way.